# About customer comparator in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a custom `class A`:

```
class A {
    String name;
    String address;
    String age;
}
```

And an `ArrayList` contains objects of class `A`.  A function `sortOnTheBasisOf()` will get input from the user about whether sorting should be done on the basis of `name`, `address` or `age`.

Now, I know that in order to sort, I need to implement the `Comparator`; however, since the sorting might need to be carried out on the basis of name, address or age, how can I implement the `Comparator` so that it would work on all?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean is there anyway to create a single comparator which works for name, address and age?

Answer (score 1):

You need three different comparators, you can use `Comparator.comparing` to easily create them, if your class has getters they will be:

```
Comparator.comparing(A::getName);
Comparator.comparing(A::getAddress);
Comparator.comparing(A::getAge);
```

Use the appropriate one in `sortOnTheBasisOf()` depending on the input.

Comment: So, if I have 20 different member variables, will I need twenty different comparators?  Is there some better way to do this (given all comparisons are in the standard way - alphabetically, numerically, etc.)?

Comment: @J.Doe Better in what way? You need choose based on which field it will be sorted, you have to do it one way or the other.

Comment: Better in the sense that it will do the sorting in the _usual_ way (as if they were normal Strings, integers, etc.

Comment: @J.Doe It will do it in the usual way, you still need to choose the field used for sorting.